# avoid page refresh clicking on RadSplitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, splitter

Page is refreshing every time when i am clicking on RadPanelItem of RadSplitter, how i can avoid it?

Note: I am used RadAjaxPanel outside RadSplitter, page is not refreshing in Mozilla but refreshing in Internet Explorer. how i can avoid it ?

Comment: Post your code and tell us where you click so that you want it to create a partial postback. Otherwise a wild guess will not help you much.